# About conditional density function.

Tags: probability

Let $X,\hspace{0.2cm}Y$ random variables with joint density 
$$f(x,y)=c \hspace{0.5cm} if \hspace{0.3cm} x^2+y^2 \leq 1$$
Compute $f(x|y)$

Mi problem is to cumpute $f_Y(y)$. I was trying to use polar coordinates but I'm confused at the moment to integrate ove $x$

Answer (score 1):

Since $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed over the unit circle, $c=\frac{1}{\pi}$ and 
$$ f(x|y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[-\sqrt{1-y^2},\sqrt{1-y^2}]}, $$
no need to use polar coordinates.